# Как отделить каталожный номер от наименования товара?

Tags: excel, office, excel-формулы

Есть файл с каталогом, нужно в один столбец поместить каталожный номер, а в другой столбец наименование товара (я сделал вручную там пару примеров)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Да что же это за дух сообщества-то такой? Не нужно мешать тем, кому понятно.

Comment: Скопируйте в вопрос текст из колонки `A`, тот, что показан на картинке.

Comment: Ручками) только так

Comment: Без конкретики по форматам каталожных номеров любая формула или макрос будет только попыткой отделить "зерна от плевел". Количество символов в номере. наличие разделителей, цифровые/буквенные символы - чем больше различий в форматах, тем дальше от автоматизации.

Answer (score 0):

Без толики ручной работы вряд-ли можно обойтись. Что могу посоветовать. Там справа, где есть пустое место. Пусть это будет `D`. Оставить `D` для индекса, в `E` скопировать `A`. Потом разобрать `E` в текст по столбцам с пробелом в качестве разделителя. В `D` сделать формулу вывода предполагаемого индекса каталожного номера, который определяется с помощью пользовательской функции `GetIndex`. Просмотреть все строки и при необходимости подкорректировать индекс. В `B` сделать формулу выбора ячейки с номером по индексу, в `C` сделать формулу объединения через пробел всего остального.

Примерно так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В шестой строке показаны формулы для пятой строки. Их нужно раскопировать по соответствующему столбцу.

Код функции `GetIndex`:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function GetIndex(x As String) As Integer
  Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
  j = 0
  For i = 1 To Len(x)
    If Mid$(x, i, 1) Like "#" Then
      j = i
      Exit For
    End If
  Next
  k = 0
  i = 1
  i = InStr(i, x, " ")
  While i < j And i > 0
    k = k + 1
    i = InStr(i + 1, x, " ")
  Wend
  GetIndex = k + 1
End Function
```

Функция определяет каталожный номер по первой цифре, встречающейся в строке (такой алгоритм разработан, исходя из иллюстрации в вопросе).

Comment: Как дела? Может, есть какие-то вопросы?